# How to find Emacs backup files?

Tags: bash, find, emacs, backup

Emacs backup files start with `.#` but I can find those in my directory. I've try:

```
find . -name '^\.#.*'
```

or

```
find . -name '.*#.*'
```

and they are not show up, and I have them. For instance if I create one just for test:

```
touch '.#test'
```

and if I try to find it using `find` command it not show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> touch .#test
> find . -name '.#*'
./.#test
```

Works! `find` uses [shell globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), *not* [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). `.` does not need to be escaped in the former because it is not a special character, it is always literal.  The glob equivalent of the regexp wildcard `.` is `?`.   Also, `*` is a wildcard in globbing, the regexp equivalent of which is `.*` (`*` being a *quantifier* and not a wildcard in regexps).

Comment: Thanks, I thought that `find` use regex for `-name`.

Comment: @jcubic no, only for `--regex`. Please remember to accept this answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: @terdon You always need to wait (I think half an hour) before accepting.

Comment: @terdon long options with double minus for find (`--regex`)? I think you fell victim to habitual typing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This answer may work well.

```
find . -regex ".*\.#.*"
```